# iterate through dict and assign value to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

how can I iterate through a dictionary and then append a value to a list?

this is what i have so far:

```
for i in range(0, len(dict)):
    x=dict[i]
    y=i
    my_string=x+y
    list[i]=my_string
```

I think the second line requires a string instead of an integer. But what would be the way to do this?

I also cant use `for value in dict` because that wouldnt work with the last line.

Thanks in advance! I am grateful for any advice!

EDIT:

My dict contains only strings;
Also I am using dict and list to make clear what data structure i am using, in my actual code they are named differently, but thanks for your tips on that :) )

Comment: 1). Dictionaries aren't iterated over by length. Use `dict.items()`, `dict.keys()`, or `dict.values()` to iterate over elements in them. 2). Use `list.append` to append items to a list. 3). Don't name your variables of type `dict` as `dict`, and same with `list`. It shadows the built-in types and makes your code confusing to read.

Comment: I guess first thing I would (strongly) recommend is to not name your variable after builtin types. For example use `d` and not `dict`

Comment: Provide a [mcve], which means show the assignments of the variables you are using

Comment: As already noted, you need to post a working script. We don't know what's in your dict. Trying to index with integer values from `range` may be odd, but if you dict keys are these integers, then it makes sense after all. Post a working script and we can figure that sort of thing out.

Answer (score 2):

You **don't have to** iterate through it at all - you can simply use:

```
dict_as_list = list(my_dict.values())
```

Your approach does **not work** because **Dictionaries** as a **data-structure** do not use **indices**, like **Lists/Arrays** in order to save items, but instead a more unrestricted **key-value** approach. Each key **has to be unique** while values **can be duplicates**.

I would **strongly suggest** for you to read the following page of the **official docs**:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Afterwards you'll have a much better understanding of **data-structures** & their appropriate **use-cases**.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes I should have been more precise in my answer, thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 2):

You can write this loop more simply as an enumeration of the values, e.g.

```
for i, x in enumerate(my_dict.values()):
   ...
```

If you're trying to build a list of `i + x` elements, you can do this in a single line as a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [i + x for i, x in enumerate(my_dict.values())]
```

Note that this assumes that the values in `my_dict` are numeric and can be added to `i` -- if they aren't, you may want to use `f"{i}{x}"` instead of `i + x` to build a concatenated string.

Answer (score 1):

- To get integers as you iterate over a something, you can use the `enumerate()` function:

  ```
  for i, item in enumerate(container):
    ...
  ```
- To append to a list, don't use `list[i]`; that's for overwriting existing items. Instead, use `list.append()`

Putting these two together, we get;

```
for i, value in enumerate(dict.values()):
    my_string=value + i
    list[i]=my_string
    list.append(my_string)
```

Or, turning it into a one-liner:

```
list = [
    value + i
    for i, value in enumerate(dict.values())
]
```

As others have noted, probably rename the `list` and `dict` variables so they're not named the same as the built-in types. Good names would be something that gives an indication of their contents.

In addition, depending on what's in the dictionary, `value + i` is unlikely to give a string; if your dictionary contain strings, you should probably use `my_string = value + str(i)`; otherwise, if you want numbers to be added, keep them as numbers and rename the variable `my_number = value + i`